# Bootstrap-table - Change properties of the search-tool

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-table

I would like to change the border color and add an icon of the right side to search-tool in the bootstrap-table framework.

Also I would like to align to the other buttons at the top of the table.

My code is:

```
/* SEARCH TOOL */

.search{
    width: 25%;
}

.fixed-table-toolbar .bs-bars,
.fixed-table-toolbar .search,
.fixed-table-toolbar .columns {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 34px;
}


<table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod'
                    data-toggle='table'
                    data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                    data-show-refresh='true'
                    data-show-toggle='true'
                    data-sort-name='name'
                    data-sort-order='desc'
                    data-show-columns='true'
                    data-pagination='true'
                    data-search='true'>

         <thead class='thead-inverse'>
           <tr>
              <th data-field='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
              <th data-field='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>   
              <th data-field='pagina' data-sortable='true'>PÀGINA</th>
              <th data-field='codigo' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>CODI</th>
              <th data-field='descripcion' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>DESCRIPCIÓ</th>
               <th data id='image' data-switchable='false'>imatge</th>
               <th data-field='pvp-cat' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CAT</th>
               <th data-field='pvp-lev' data-sortable='true'>PVP-LEV</th> 
               <th data-field='pvp-and' data-sortable='true'>PVP-AND</th>
               <th data-field='pvp-cen' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CEN</th>
               <th data-field='pvp-nor' data-sortable='true'>PVP-NOR</th>
               <th data-field='pvp-vas' data-sortable='true'>PVP-VAS</th>
               <th data-field='fecha-mod' data-sortable='true'>FECHA-MOD</th>
               <th data-field='user' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>USER</th>
               <th data-field='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr>   
                <!— Function to load registres —>       
             </tr>  
          </tbody>
     </table> 


 if (this.options.search) {
            html = [];
            html.push(
                '<div class="pull-' + this.options.searchAlign + ' search">',
                sprintf('<input class="form-control' + 
                    sprintf(' input-%s', this.options.iconSize) +
                    '" type="text" placeholder="%s">',
                    this.options.formatSearch()),
                '</div>');

            this.$toolbar.append(html.join(''));
            $search = this.$toolbar.find('.search input');
            $search.off('keyup drop').on('keyup drop', function (event) {
                if (that.options.searchOnEnterKey && event.keyCode !== 13) {
                    return;
                }

                if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [37, 38, 39, 40]) > -1) {
                    return;
                }

                clearTimeout(timeoutId); // doesn't matter if it's 0
                timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                    that.onSearch(event);
                }, that.options.searchTimeOut);
            });

            if (isIEBrowser()) {
                $search.off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function (event) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // doesn't matter if it's 0
                    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                        that.onSearch(event);
                    }, that.options.searchTimeOut);
                });
            }
        }
```

It doesn't works. I think that the problem is that the search-tool use an input tag and the class form-control, I do not sure it.

Comment: add the html part also

Comment: Ok, already it's updated.

Comment: I dont see any search filed in your html part. if you have input field and type is search you can add border color with
input[type=search] {
        border-color: red;
} 
and if you have problem with on click input search field border you can set 
input[type=search]:focus{
    border-color: red; 
    outline: 0;
}

Comment: I have update the code with the js file. In the JS is defined the style of input box is this where it's defined the style of search box in the css document.

Comment: replace the type with text 
input[type=text] {
        border-color: red;
} 
input[type=text]:focus{
    border-color: red; 
    outline: 0;
}

here is the fiddle I dont get te search field with your script

Comment: ok got it you used additional cnd bootstrap table js and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to do like this [Live Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tjbaezid/na5tp16c/4/). I also comment out where I add or change. And btw you don't need that script you added in your question. Any Question ask me in comment. Happy coding :)

```js
$(function(){
$(".search").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>');
/* add the span inside search div with append box*/
});
```

```css
.search {
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .search span {
      position: absolute; /*Set search icon*/
      right: 10px;
      top: 10px;
    }
    .search input[type=text]{
      border-color: red; /*Set the border color for search box*/
    }
    .search input[type=text]:focus{
     outline:none;
     box-shadow:none; /*If you dont need the shadow on click*/
    }
    
    .fixed-table-toolbar .bs-bars,
    .fixed-table-toolbar .search,
    .fixed-table-toolbar .columns {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      line-height: 34px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
</head>
    
    <body>
     <table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod' data-toggle='table' data-toolbar='#toolbar' data-show-refresh='true' data-show-toggle='true' data-sort-name='name' data-sort-order='desc' data-show-columns='true' data-pagination='true' data-search='true'>

  <thead class='thead-inverse'>
    <tr>
      <th data-field='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
      <th data-field='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>
      <th data-field='pagina' data-sortable='true'>PÀGINA</th>
      <th data-field='codigo' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>CODI</th>
      <th data-field='descripcion' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>DESCRIPCIÓ</th>
      <th data id='image' data-switchable='false'>imatge</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-cat' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CAT</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-lev' data-sortable='true'>PVP-LEV</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-and' data-sortable='true'>PVP-AND</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-cen' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CEN</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-nor' data-sortable='true'>PVP-NOR</th>
      <th data-field='pvp-vas' data-sortable='true'>PVP-VAS</th>
      <th data-field='fecha-mod' data-sortable='true'>FECHA-MOD</th>
      <th data-field='user' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>USER</th>
      <th data-field='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!— Function to load registres —>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Script CDN's-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```